# HIbernate : Saving 2 related objects in the same transaction using native query throws ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate

Let's say I have a parent/child model and I want to save a parent and his children in the same transaction, using only native sql query.

I use a preparedStatement to insert the parent and get his id:

```
        session.doWork(new Work() { 

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Here is the query:

```
final String query = "insert into parent(id,name) values (?,?)
```

I get the parent id like this:

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs!=null && rs.next()) {
                parent.setId(rs.getInt(1));
```

Then, in the same work, I use another preparedStatement to insert his children with a foreign key to his parent.

I checked if it's still the same transaction, using its hashcode and it's the same.

That's when I get the ConstraintViolationException, saying the parent id doesn't exist.

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:219)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:365)

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CHILDREN_REFERENCE_PARENT". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.PARENT", column 'ID'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1522)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
```

Though, if I do a select on the parent id before inserting a child, it says that he exists.

I don't know if what I want to do is possible, how could I be sure to insert both parent and children in the same transaction using only native sql queries?

Thanks,

/Maxime

Comment: Are you sure it's the same transaction?

Comment: Show your query.. show some more code...

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace of the error? model class, table schema etc...?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, I had shift two columns in the second insert, that's why I had the contraint violation exception.

Sorry about that.

This thread can be deleted.